# Performance gap between np.linalg.solve and scipy.linalg.cho_solve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I am trying to find `alpha` by solving two systems of linear equations that involve Cholesky decomposition. `scipy` has a special function to do so. There is a significant performance gap between `scipy` and `numpy`. Can I achieve performance as good as `scipy` in `numpy` with any other way? (assume that I am not allowed to use scipy).

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy

def numpy_cho_solve(N,M):
    for seed in range(N):
        np.random.seed(seed)
        x = np.random.rand(M,1)
        y = np.random.rand(M,1)
        k = x@x.T + np.eye(M)# M*M
        L = np.linalg.cholesky(k)
        alpha = np.linalg.solve(L.T, np.linalg.solve(L, y))
        
def scipy_cho_solve(N,M):
    for seed in range(N):
        np.random.seed(seed)
        x = np.random.rand(M,1)
        y = np.random.rand(M,1)
        k = x@x.T + np.eye(M)# M*M
        L = np.linalg.cholesky(k)
        alpha = scipy.linalg.cho_solve((L,True), y)

%timeit numpy_cho_solve(100,100)
%timeit scipy_cho_solve(100,100)
```

Output

```
317 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
76.9 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward- and back- substitution steps of Cholesky decomposition method are very fast but not vectorizable, so `numpy` can't help much.  You'd need a compiled function (as `scipy` implements) - but if you can't use `scipy` I doubt you can use `numba` (which is usually used for making c-compiled functions for `numpy`).

`np.linalg.solve` tries to solve the simple forward substitution step by naively applying LU substitution, so it takes much longer than a purpose-built function (or even not using Cholesky at all).

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly ```scipy``` does here which gives it a performance boost? I am willing to write the same using ```numpy``` if possible or maybe shall I look into the source code of ```scipy```?

Comment: `scipy` uses a compiled function, that's written in `c`.  Python is an interpreted, not compiled, language.  So you can't do the same thing as `scipy` unless you can 1) write and compile a `c` function that's callable from `python` or 2) use `numba` to do it

Answer (score 1):

Considering you can use only numpy, then `np.linalg.solve` is the best function for solving linear equations as it gives accurate results. You can use `inv` and `transpose` functions of numpy, but the accurate result will be of `solve` function.

Comment: Can you show with an example how ```inv``` and ```transpose``` help here?